# Why leveldb's bloomfilter's bit array needs to be partitioned into many filterblocks?

Tags: leveldb, bloom-filter

Since table is opened, the whole filter blocks will be kept in memory, will it be simpler if there's only one bloomfilter bit array?

Answer (score 1):

RocksDB uses a different design: it uses [Bloom filters covering the whole SST file](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Features-Not-in-LevelDB).

I'm not very familiar with the leveldb design, but likely the reason why leveldb doesn't is because of simplicity. Also, if each block has a separate Bloom filter, then only one block needs to be kept in memory. So, leveldb is optimized for the case where lookups are related, while RocksDB is optimized for speed. Combining the Bloom filter slightly reduces the Bloom filter size, but requires to load the whole Bloom filter.